# How to make an HTTP proxy that points to a specific server

Tags: python, proxy

I am trying to set up an HTTP proxy using Python. I found this library on GitHub: https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py. However, I noticed that it is a generic proxy--it extracts the target server from the original HTTP request, and uses that to construct it's own HTTP request.

What I'd like to make is a proxy that points to only one server, www.targetserver.com. How can I go about this?

Comment: Hi, I am author of the library you linked. proxy.py does so because it support proxy authentication and other features which require parsing incoming request.  v1.0.0+ supports plugin and for your use case you want RedirectToCustomServerPlugin, see example implementation here https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py/blob/develop/plugin_examples.py#L85-L104 . Hope it helps, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use python twisted library

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import proxy, server

site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('www.yahoo.com', 80, ''))
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```